# series of double indices

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_{n,i}$ be a double indices sequence with $a_{n,i}\geq0$. For all $i\in\mathbb{N}$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n,i}=0$. While for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists $i>n$ such that $a_{n,i}\geq M_{i}>0$. Consider $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{n,i}$, should it converges to zero?
I try using Fatou's lemma but nothing happens. I think it will not converge to zero but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: anything can happen: divergence to infinity or whatever. The $M_i$ doesn't give any information

Comment: So it can converge to zero as well?